# Fast load image from sdcard

Tags: android, image, performance

I want that load images from sdcard to listview but i dont need  image in big size. size 60dip * 60dip is Sufficient. i am using below codes in thread but however this is slow.i  need load images in fast way.

```
public Bitmap loadImage(String imagePath){

//load bitmap in real size
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

int width = bmp.getWidth();
int height = bmp.getHeight();

//determine size and scale      
float newWidth = convertDipToPixel(60, getApplicationContext());//60 dip
float scale = ((float) newWidth) / width;

// createa matrix for the manipulation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// resize the bit map
matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

return resizedBitmap;}
```

Answer (score 0):

check [android query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) and [image loading using android query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading)

its really fast, try it.

```
File file = new File(path);        

//load image from file, down sample to target width of 300 pixels  
aq.id(R.id.avatar).image(file, 300);
```

---

you can also use [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

```
String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card

// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView (or any other view 
//  which implements ImageAware interface)

imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```